# GCP Cloud Run Spring App - How to specify flyway volume

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, flyway, google-cloud-run

In my spring app, I externalized flyway migration

spring.flyway.locations=filesystem:/var/migration

When using docker run I specify

docker run --name papp -p 9000:2000 -v "C:...\db\migration":/var/migration

How can I specify this in Cloud Run >> VAriables and Secrets

What values do I need to supply for **-v "C:...\db\migration":/var/migration**

(I created a bucket and uploaded file in Cloud Storage..assuming files should be there)

[image]

Comment: Google Cloud Run does not support mounting volumes or file systems at this time in GA status.

Comment: so how can I supply a migration script V3 for my application without much work i.e building a new version etc?

Comment: You could store the script on Cloud Storage and read it from Cloud Run.

Comment: @JohnHanley yep, can have files added there, but how do I need to read cloud storage files? code or  configuration ? I would like to unit test any change I make

Comment: You would add code to your application to interface with Cloud Storage. Martin provided a link to three storage options for Cloud Run.

Answer (score 1):

The form you have there is being described as:

> Mount each secret as a volume, which makes the secret available to the container **as files**.

If you cannot explain in how far `/var/migration` would be a "secret", this might be the wrong approach. One likely cannot [mount that volume as a secret](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets#console); just mount with `docker run -v`.

But there are secrets for [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/documentation), which you could mount eg. as `flyway.properties` file:

```
flyway.user=databaseUser
flyway.password=databasePassword
flyway.schemas=schema1,schema2
```

And generally all the other configuration parameters, as well:
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/

Comment: ok I agree its not a secret like a password, but the scripts  are obviously the database structure creators. I don't have the flyway properties in my app. as it works with db details I would like to know how can I provide scripts location for CloudRun

Comment: @KrisSwat If you need to mount some kind of file-system, this could be a bucket: https://medium.com/google-cloud/3-great-options-for-persistent-storage-with-cloud-run-f1581ee05164 ...while one can create builders (also some container), which eg. then builds the desired application container (it's more indirect, but more separation of duties).